# Jquery select a var?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$.get('example.com',function(data){
link = $(data #someid).attr("href") // how to do this???
})
```

I load a page from other web (ex: $.get) and pass it to data, now how to use .attr() or Selectors on the data (sorry for my english problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know what is the content of the data, but if it is valid HTML, you could do it as this

```
$.get('example.com',function(data){
link = $("#test",$(data)).attr("href") // this is how you should do it
});
```

Imagine data HTML is

```
<a id="test" href="http://test.com">This is a link</a>
```

Hope helps
:)

Comment: `$(data).find("#someid")` seems somewhat cleaner to me. Also don't forget the cross-domain restrictions

Comment: cross-domain restrictions isn't my problem in this (i write chrome app)

Answer (score 0):

You have a few syntax errors:

You need to add a data variable in the callback function:

```
$.get('example.com', function(data) {
```

Inside, you can look it up like this:

```
link = $("#someid", $(data)).attr('href')
```

Here's all of it:

```
$.get('example.com', function(data) {
    link = $("#someid", data).attr('href')
});
```